# Regex - How to get src and alt from Image

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I need to get from all the images the src and alt of the html code. I managed to get it but I have the following problem:

- If the image has no alt, it does not detect me the image. In these cases I need to get only the src.

The following code works with problem:
https://regex101.com/r/3Vlkql/1

```
(<img\s)[^>]*(src=\S+)[^>]*(\salt=["|'].*?["|'])[^>]*(\/?>)
```

Substitution:

```
$1$2$3$4
```

Result:

```
<img src="https://example.com/image" alt="example1">
```

Problem: My regex only detect if have src and alt. But if not have alt, the regex not detect me. How can I do with regex to get both?

This not match with regex:

```
<img src="https://example.com/image">
```

- src & alt
- only src

I dont have problem if i need to use 2 regex to get my purpose.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: This regex:<img(?![^>]*\balt=)[^>]*?> Match images that not have alt, but how can i group to get <img src="domain.com/image"> only for this images that not contain alt –

Comment: You are starting to discover why you don't want to parse HTML with regexes.

Comment: Have you watched the steps counter in regex101? This pattern already looks laborious. What if `alt` is before `src`? Doing [this with regex](https://regex101.com/r/3Vlkql/4) will be complicated and hard to maintain besides that it can't be used on any arbitrary html.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `?` at end of group for optional group patterns:

its work fine: `/(<img\s)[^>]*(src=\S+)[^>]*(\salt=["|'].*?["|'])?[^>]*(\/?>)/gm`

and here the live link you can check demo: https://regex101.com/r/u2uWGX/1

[image]

[image]

Comment: But not work with:
<img class="aligncenter  wp-image-15664" src="https://example.com"  srcset="https://example.com/" sizes="(max-width: 557px) 100vw, 557px" width="557" height="314" _mstalt="1316237">

Comment: <img(?![^>]*\balt=)[^>]*?>
Match images that not have alt, but how can i group to get <img src="domain.com/image"> only for this images that not contain alt

Comment: its work with `<img class="aligncenter wp-image-15664" src="example.com" srcset="example.com" sizes="(max-width: 557px) 100vw, 557px" width="557" height="314" _mstalt="1316237">`  too! see the picture

Comment: use this one `/(<img\s)[^>]*(src=\S+)[^>]*(\salt=["|'].*?["|'])?[^>]*(\/?>)/gm`

Comment: Can you check why dont work? https://regex101.com/r/qeNPvz/1

Comment: i need the alt also

Comment: it didn't work because you didn't copy my regex! its different! my regex has `?`  in here `["|'])?[^>]` so use this : `(<img\s)[^>]*(src=\S+)[^>]*(\salt=["|'].*?["|'])?[^>]*(\/?>)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of `img` elements in your HTML. You can also get the `src` and `alt` value by looping a `HTMLCollection`.

Demo **:**

```js
const imgCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (let item of imgCollection) {
  console.log('src :', item.src)
  console.log('alt :', item.alt)
}
```

```html
<img src="https://example.com/image" alt="example1">
<img src="https://example.com/image">
```